# Alternative to optim confusion matrix for multi label classification in torch

Tags: lua, statistics, torch, confusion-matrix

I have a convnet that produces multi label output. Ie: each image can be labelled with 0 to 10 labels. The output is a tensor of size 10, containing 1s (indicating a label at that index) and -1s (no label at that index). Targets are in the same format. So:

```
{1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Indicates labels 1-3 and 5-10. Multi label output cannot be used with the confusion matrix of the torch optim package. What are some good alternatives for evaluating prediction accuracy?

Ideally, I would like to know how accurately **each label** is being predicted, in terms of false positives, true positives, etc. One idea would be to make 10 separate confusion matrices and feed each the data for one index. Is there a better solution though?

Any input appreciated.

---

Update: the above approach worked fine, but it's cumbersome when there are many labels. I just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Is the proposed approach somehow flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made separate confusion matrices for each label, split the output predictions, and added them to the appropriate matrix. By co-plotting classification accuracy for training/validation set, it's pretty easy to interpret.